# How does 2 applications know to stop the other video playback?

Tags: android, youtube, android-videoview, netflix, android-picture-in-picture

Recently I recognized Android's behavior:

1. start video playback in one application (in my case it's Netflix Android app)
2. go to Youtube Android app - Netflix video preview goes into PIP mode and playback is rolling
3. in Youtube app start a video - then Netflix PIP playback stops

How is that possible and what api is used to inform the other app to stop it's playback? Does it happen independently from the Netflix/ Youtube app on the level of Android OS itself? Is it described somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Apps manage audio focus by calling `requestAudioFocus()` and `abandonAudioFocus()`.

Apps must also register an `AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener` with both calls in order to receive callbacks and manage their own audio level.

Comment: Ah, so it happens via audio focus? I'd never guess that :P